# Ionic2: Property 'present' does not exist on type 'NavController'

Tags: ionic2

I am using `Ionic 2 rc4`.  I am following the advise [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-loading-component-error/51585/2) and am trying to do the following:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
        ...
    this.nav.present(this.loading).then(() => {
```

However, to me it looks like the `NavController` does not have a `present` function, because I get:

> ```
> [ts] Property 'present' does not exist on type 'NavController'.
> any
> ```

Am I correct, or am I doing something wrong?  How do they get to access this "phantom" function?

Any advise appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here is my code that results in the following error (on `this.loading.present().then(() => {`):

> `"Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null"`

It presents loading the first time. but after the `alert` is presented if `submit()` is run again, it gets this error.

```
submit() {
            this.loading.present().then(() => {
                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'Verify Email',
                    subTitle: 'Please verify your email address before you log in.',
                    message: 'Check your Spam folder if you cannot find the email.',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Resend',
                            handler: data => {
                                firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().then((data) => {
                                    this.doAlert('Verify Email', 'Verification Email Sent.').then((data) => {
                                        //navCtrl.setRoot(navCtrl.getActive());
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Okay',
                            handler: data => {
                                //navCtrl.setRoot(navCtrl.getActive());
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
                alert.present();
                this.loading.dismiss();
            });
}
```

Comment: do you define your NavController with attribute ViewChild? @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController

Comment: Have you defined the NavController in your constructor?

Comment: Yes, I define it in the constructor:  `constructor(public nav: NavController, ...)`. Not as a `@ViewChild`.  Is this incorrect? Why should it change the api?  I can still do `this.nav.pop()` for example.

Comment: If I use `@ViewChild`, it makes no difference.

Comment: @Richard if I understand correctly, the error occurs when you call `submit` the second time.

Comment: That's correct. The first time it has no problems.

Comment: updated the answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-3) for **Beta 11**

They have removed `present` function from `Navcontroller`.

You need to refactor your code and use some other function based on your requirement. 
`this.loading.present()`

For the error, check the [Loading controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) docs.

> Note that after the component is dismissed, it will not be usable
>   anymore and another one must be created. This can be avoided by
>   wrapping the creation and presentation of the component in a reusable
>   function

Just do :

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
   //loading properties
          });
```

inside `submit()` before `this.loading.present()`

Comment: Yes, I am using `rc4`.  Thank you. I do try `this.loading.present()`, I get `"Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null"`. I was trying to fix this error, when I read that one should do this: `this.nav.present(this.loading)`. I believe this error happens when `this.loading` is not ready.  Is there anyway to detect when it is ready?

Comment: Thank you. You solved my issue. Appreciate it again.