# How to use LoadingController - ionic 2 on button click

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

I have used following code for button click

```
<button class="action-button getstarted" ion-button clear small (click)="loader()" >Loader</button>
```

And the function is

```
loader(){
        this.loading.present();
        console.log('hello');
        }
```

It throws error this.enteringView.pageRef(...) is null
how to fix this issue?
what is wrong here?

Comment: where are you creating the loading controller?

Comment: i have created the loading controller in constructor itself

Comment: and `enteringView` is?

Comment: below the contructor function,In enteringView  function also i have used loading present  is works fine but why? button click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41932924/4826457 check my answer here

Comment: once loading controller is dismissed, it cannot be reused

Comment: Oh! this.nav.present(this.loading); it returns present does not exit on NavController

Comment: that is different error in that question. But issue is you need to create new loading controller each time you need to present it

Comment: Thank you so much i have created new loading controller